# Fastest way to fetch posts across a multisite

Tags: multisite, wp-query

What's the fastest way to fetch posts/content across a multisite? I had been using SimplePie RSS feeds, but I'm now investigating [`switch_to_blog()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog). As `switch_to_blog` appears to be quite simple to use, I'd much rather use this implementation, but wanted to make sure that it would remain speedy.

Answer (score 1):

yup it is fast, it would be even better for you to use the [WP Transients API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API) to cache your query for a short period.

Basically:

```
if($saved = get_site_transient('SOME_SORT_OF_ID')){
    echo $saved;
} else {

    ob_start();

    switch_to_blog(x); // x being the blog id your want to switch to
    // Do your quering and echoing here

    restore_current_blog(); // Revert to current blog   

    set_site_transient("SOME_SORT_OF_ID", ob_get_contents(), (60 * 60)); //Save query for one hour

    ob_end_flush(); // Echo and End Buffering      

}
```